# How to change group for apache user in Fedora

Tags: fedora, apache-httpd, php, group

I have directory project in home directory and symlink to it in /var/www/html

And I can't open files because got error 403, I set the Group in httpd.conf to kuba (my main user/group)

run `systemctl restart httpd` but simple php script like this:

```
<?php echo exec("id"); ?>
```

Display:

```
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache) context=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
```

I've also tried to add apache to kuba group but with no effect. How can I make apache run as group kuba?

I'm using this in my httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**UPDATE**
After few reboots, because of installation of VirtualBox, I got this from php script:

```
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache),1000(kuba) 
context=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
```

but the php script in localhost/projects still return 403 error. I don't see any SELinux errors but just in case I've executed `setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1` as in here [Apache can't open file that is a symlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388713/apache-cant-open-file-that-is-a-symlink)

Comment: Look in */etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf* and change `Group`.

Comment: @Thomas I've edited that file and the value is kuba.

Comment: setting `chmod g+rx /home/kuba` resolve the issue, it's not related to changing group but actual issue I had.